# GroupModel cannot be cast to Another Model

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I'm trying to pull data from web service to linked spinners, no data to two spinner at the same time. And this section of the code gives an error:

```
spinnerFleet.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            FleetModel selectedItem = (FleetModel) adapterView.getSelectedItem(); /*I think there was an error in this part of the code */
            int vgID = displayIdData(selectedItem);
            String jsonString = "{\"params1\":\"" + session_id + "\"," +
                    "\"params2\":\"5\"," +
                    "\"params3\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params4\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params5\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params6\":\""+vgID+"\"," +
                    "\"params7\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params8\":\"" + user_id + "\"}";
            new LoadSpinnerGroupTask().execute(jsonString);
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to pull data from web service to linked spinners, no data to two spinner at the same time. And this section of the code gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `adapterView.getSelectedItem()` returns GroupModel, not FleetModel. So if FleetModel doesn't extend GroupModel, it will throw cast error.

What is the data type in your Adapter items ? Change it to FleetModel, or just write `GroupModel selectedItem = (GroupModel) adapterView.getSelectedItem();`

Try it like this:

```
spinnerFleet.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            FleetModel selectedItem = stateAdapter.getItem(i); /*I think there was an error in this part of the code */
            int vgID = displayIdData(selectedItem);
            String jsonString = "{\"params1\":\"" + session_id + "\"," +
                    "\"params2\":\"5\"," +
                    "\"params3\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params4\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params5\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params6\":\""+vgID+"\"," +
                    "\"params7\":\"0\"," +
                    "\"params8\":\"" + user_id + "\"}";
            new LoadSpinnerGroupTask().execute(jsonString);
        }
```

Comment: get the id of the selected element from the top spinner,I want to bring the spinner group at the bottom according to the id I bought

Comment: want to bring group by fleet id

Comment: Okay, But if that line says cannot cast to GroupModel, so adapterView.getSelectedItem() is returning GroupModel. You cannot cast different objects. Please share code of your Adapter that you use for spinnerFleet

Comment: Since i cannot comment yet on your post, i will write it here. So try accessing FleetModel object using adapter.  Like this: 

This is your adapter
StateAdapter stateAdapter = ...;

And this is how you get FleetModel
FleetModel selectedItem = stateAdapter.getItem(i);

I also updated my answer